# 400 Bad Request in angular in Http Get request

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

When I try this URL : http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1 directly I get response:

[image]

But when I try to access this same URL from my angular application It is giving 400 Bad Request.

In Service:

```
getEmpAPI = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee'

getEmployee(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.getEmpAPI}/${id}`)
  }
```

In Component:

```
onClick(evt: any, index) {
evt.preventDefault();
let id = index + 1;
this.empDataService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(
  (emp) => {
    console.log(emp);        
  }
)
```

}

[image]

For reference this the API page all I have. 
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/

Please help:

Comment: Any one please help!!

Comment: Found its get request should be like this:      /employee/{id} GET JSON

Comment: another thing if you remove the cookies from browser and try again the url directly in browser. It will give error 400, But once you refresh the same url the data will start coming. This means on first hit something is set inside browser cookies and refreshing it again data starts coming because now cookie is set. But I don't know how to handle this thing in angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a employee with the id of 0? in the above example you are using 1

Comment: sorry I update the question was some wrong edits. Check know